# Using Google visualizations how can you trigger a select event on a specific row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I currently have one table that that when a row is clicked on, I would like to simulate clicking the same row on a GV table. Here is the listener.

```
$(".mytable tbody tr td").click(function() {
    var colIndex = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
    var rowIndex = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
    google.visualization.events.trigger(chart, 'select', null);
});
```

This is triggering the select event properly, but what I need is to be able to get the row in that callback like so.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "select", function() {
    var selection = chart2.getSelection();
    var item = selection[0];
    console.log(item, selection);
});
```

When clicking on the GV table item contains an object with row and column. How can I trigger the select on the table on a specific row and get it the same as if it was clicked on itself?

I did find one way to do it, though I would rather just be able to use the same code for both routes.

```
$(".mytable tbody tr td").click(function() {
    var colIndex = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
    var rowIndex = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
    google.visualization.events.trigger(chart, 'select', {"row": rowIndex, "col": colIndex});
});

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "select", function(data) {
    if(typeof data["row"] != "undefined") {
        item = data;
    }
    else {
        var selection = chart2.getSelection();
        var item = selection[0];
    }console.log(data, item);
});
```

I also have tried using jquery to click on the proper cell (this would be ideal).

```
$(".google-visualization-table .top-level table tbody tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ") td:eq(" + colIndex + ")").click();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below synchronizes click on the DOM table with a google visualization table :

```
$(".mytable").on('click', 'tbody td', function(e) {
   chart.setSelection([{row: e.toElement.parentNode.rowIndex-1}]);
   google.visualization.events.trigger(chart, 'select', {});
})
```

The `select` event is fired on the GV table exactly as it was clicked itself.
demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/7v487nhf/**

**Note**: You can only select entire rows, or multiple rows, so setting `col` is needless - ending up in `null` any way.

Comment: Works like a champ! Thanks David!